# SSIS no longer open DtsDebugHost.exe still running

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-data-tools

I often need to write Ad-Hoc SSIS ingestion flows to import hundreds of GB into our SQL Server.

```
Occasionally, after letting the package run over night, the SLN will no longer be open when I check in the morning.  However the DtsDebugHost.exe process will still be running.
```

Most recently, I moved 390 GB between SQL Servers using a simple DataFlow with an `OLE DB Source` and `OLE DB Destination`

After checking on the process in the morning, my Visual Studio was not open, but DtsDebugHost.exe was running, and ultimately, the destination had the full row count which I would expect. This indicates that the process continued to run despite the VS GUI crashing.  Further, the final step in my Package is to execute a Success/Failure email. This did not execute, so it appears that the DTS Debug finished, but only ran until it finished the task which it was on (my DataFlow).

In the past, after this occurred I have copied the SLN onto a Server with 700+GB Memory, and had no issues. My suspicion is that this is memory related, but have not found similar issues online. Any insight is appreciated

I am using SSDT 2017 targeting a SQL Server 2016 machine